# Conda environment creation from yml does work locally but not on AWS SageMaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, conda, environment, amazon-sagemaker

I have a private GitHub repository in which I included an `environment.yml` file.

**What works:**

When I am trying to create an environment locally from a different laptop (compared to the one on which I have created the repository) like that

```bash
conda env create -n MyEnvName --file environment.yml
```

it works. While running it prints prints the following to tell me what it tries to download and extract. Perfect, thats what I want.

```
Downloading and Extracting Packages:
...
```

The local configurations are

```bash
$ conda -V
conda 22.9.0
$ python3 -V
Python 3.10.5
```

**What doesn't work:**

Now I tried to do exactly the same on an AWS SageMaker account in which the configurations are

```bash
$ conda -V
conda 22.9.0
$ python3 -V
Python 3.7.12
```

However, now when I run the `conda env create -n MyEnvName --file environment.yml` command it prints

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:
...
```

followed by a lot packages from the `dependencies` in the `environment.yml`, e.g. `argon2-cffi-bindings=21.2.0=py310h1961e1f_2`.

Here the the `conda info` of the SageMaker instance

```
     active environment : JupyterSystemEnv
    active env location : /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/ec2-user/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/ec2-user/.condarc
          conda version : 22.9.0
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.7.10.final.0
       virtual packages : __linux=4.14.294=0
                          __glibc=2.17=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /home/ec2-user/anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/ec2-user/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/22.9.0 requests/2.23.0 CPython/3.7.10 Linux/4.14.294-150.533.amzn1.x86_64 amzn/2018.03 glibc/2.17
                UID:GID : 500:500
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

I am very new to environment creation and would really appreciate any help! I tried to solve this for days now and it's super frustrating.